# Displaying 2 Array series in a 2x2 matrix with WPF

Tags: arrays, wpf, vb.net, data-binding, time-series

How to **layout to WPF UI** the **values from two `Array` series** so that the data would be displayed nicely in a **2x2-matrix** according to the picture below. (`Array` length is determined only at runtime and not known beforehand).

Example data objects and values:

```
DatesSeries(131) As DateTime = {#2014-01-01#, #2014-02-01# , ... , #2024-12-01#]
ValueSeries(131) As Single = {300, 400, ... , 7000}
```

Desired UI:

[image]

(White areas must be editable and gray areas must be not editable. Total line should auto-calculate sum of the above 12 rows).

*Since the desired UI "looks" like a `DataGrid`, my first thinking was*

1. Use `DataGrid` control - create new `IEnumerable` object from those two `Arrays` with 13 items in it (one for each month + 1 for total line) - set `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to that list.

   This feels stupid since I need to reform the existing objects and I know the numer of items in the list beforehand but I DON'T know the number of columns needed.

*Secondly I thought*

2. Use some kind of 3rd party spreadsheet control. I suppose none of them support WPF data binding leading to a lot of manual code-behind and visual styling to set this up.

*Thirdly, I was becoming already desperate and thought*

3. Insert bunch of `TextBlocks` and `TextBoxes` in a `Grid` with 14 Rows and 12 (or as many as needed) Columns. With the above data, this would lead to 167 individual UI elements and quite horrible data binding I suppose.

None of these feels good for me.

Since the need to layout dates and corresponding values as a time-series must be a common need out there I must be missing some better solution for this.

Could somebody point out a feasible solution with WPF to this.

Comment: You need a pivot table. I don't see how any IEnumerable structure is going to help you. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70d9c898-b271-4f7b-9757-4b48e35e2512/the-missing-wpf-pivottable-control The problem is that you have a dynamic amount of columns, not rows. The data grid is constructing your columns based on the properties in your items source.

Answer (score 0):

The data series can't be used as DataSource directly, anyway you have to *reform the existing objects*.

Create a 11 (columns) x 13 (rows)  `DataTable` from the Value series and set it as the DataSource of the `DataGrid`. You need to do some math, of course, since you don't know the length of value series beforehand.

In XAML, specify the header styles for the DataGrid, and also set different style to the `Total` Row, you can get the desired UI.

Comment: DataTable/DataGrid solution is totally fine. With that, I'd like to get some help with creating the IEnumerable and especially how to pass the edited values on the DataGrid (white area on the picture) back to the original data array.

Comment: When a value in the `DataGrid` is edited, the `DataTable` is updated automatically, you can register [an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `DataTable` to get notified when a value is edited, in the event handler, you can copy the new value in `DataTable` to the original Value Serials.

Comment: I can't help you on the code because I am on a tablet that can only be used to write emails, and I am not familiar with VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a comprehensive explanation by John Smith on Code project. Check this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37241/Displaying-a-Data-Matrix-in-WPF